# GridView Delete Confirm ButtonField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to delete a row form my gridview with confirm by javascript.

My gridview looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="delete" Text="Delete" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I already tried do with TempleField and it works, but the problem is getting the value of the select row to delete from database.

I tried like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" CommandName="delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And tried get the value like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            string id = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            Response.Write(id);
        }
}
```

But it throws a FormatException on

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Can somebody help me? Sorry but my English is bad.

Comment: _"I tried like this"_ So did it work? If not, what happened instead?

Comment: You need to add `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Yourrowidfieldvalue") %>'` in the button tag

Comment: Ok, i added now give me that error:"ArgumentOutOfRangeException" on line 'string id = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.ToString();'

Comment: What did you add as your command argument ? If your using it as index then use `<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>`

Comment: I'm using the same way you are in your second example. But in the end of my confirm I use `;` and the delete is `Delete`. Works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `CommandArgument` from the button tag

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx) is more info on how to use CommandArgument

Comment: Thaks for the help, and for the people who try it.